# Angular material-expansionpanel title style

Tags: dart, angular-material2, angular-dart, angular-components

I want to change the **title** style of the Angular Dart material-expansionpanel.

[image]

If I use the following CSS, the content style change (p.ex. radio group) but the title does not change style.

```
material-expansionpanel {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

What do I need to do to change the style of the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the style is encapsulated you need to use one of our mixins or ::ng-deep to break the encapsulation. Since there isn't a mixin for this you can do.

```
:host ::ng-deep header .primary-text {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The `:host` is to keep the scope to the current component so it doesn't leak out. `::ng-deep` breaks encapsulation and the rest is the selector.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used AngularDart before, but from the examples, I think you have to target the `panel-name` class to style the expansion panel header:

```css
.panel-name {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image: DevTools CSS]

Comment: For me, unfortunatale it did not work. The content was bold, but the title not.

Comment: Very close, but it is using style encapsulation so you would need to break it using ::ng-deep see below.